# Why would it be impossible to mannually test AES algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, aes

I have *this* teacher who asked to study AES encryption algorithm, a C code implementation and do a bench testing of it.

So, I've not even tried to do a calculation of the number of *steps* it would take, but rather I'd like to have these rational reasons why a human **can´t** or **might not** go for it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to benchmark AES?

Comment: I'm sorry, I reck on that just don't know this term in english then ... I mean *manually* proof the algorithm with pen and paper.

Comment: Bench test term is from EE world, but it basically means manually test before use....

Comment: So, what would be the term for pen and paper proof or test?

Comment: @Diego - So you want a mathematical proof? I believe all encryption algorithms have a formal proof, otherwise they wouldn't be guaranteed to not corrupt your data. You can start with that if you like, but it might take a while.

Comment: No, not for the mathematical proof. I mean for going for *implementing* AES following the algorithm with pen, mind and paper

Comment: Please don't cross post - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/204446/why-is-it-impossible-to-bech-test-test-aes-algorithm

Comment: @tjameson Note that there is *no* mathematical proof for symmetrical ciphers to be secure. Some algorithms do have a formal proof, but symmetrical ciphers don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is enough scope for misunderstanding and ambiguity in a cryptographic algorithm that it is standard practice to release example inputs and outputs (test vectors) with the specification of the algorithm, so you don't have to work through the algorithm by hand. There appear to be test vectors in the specfication at http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/. In fact, appendix B of fips-197.pdf appears to show how the state table evolves during a single encryption.

Of course, for a system like AES, where it is not practical to test every possible input and key, you can always argue that while testing can find errors it can never prove the absence of errors.

Comment: It depends what the teacher asked him. and you need to consider padding, IV ect...

Answer (score 0):

Anything a computer can do - you can do as well.... they don't use magic for calculation.

To test your algorithm, you should encrypt a small text and than decrypt and see that you get the same results (it will prove the algorithm works, it won't prove it's AES....)

Comment: But number of calcs is BIG

Comment: Agree with Dani, there's no magic involved, just encode "Test" or something small. Yes, it could take 30 mins or more, but hey, that's why people don't do it by hand. I remember learning AES and some other encryption methods by hand when I was at uni 2 years ago, so it's not unreasonable.